# Spring Boot Kafka: Unable to start consumer due to NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

With in my spring boot service while trying to start a kafka consumer seeing NoSuchBeanDefinitionException and unable to start the service itself.

Below is my bean class which has all the required beans created for Kafka configuration

Spring Boot Version: 1.5.2.RELEASE

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.EnableKafka;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer;

import com.ns.kafka.gateway.dtos.GatewayCallBackMessage;

@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class GatewayCallbackToPNConsumerConfig {
 @Bean
 public Map < String, Object > consumerProps() {
  Map < String, Object > props = new HashMap < > ();
  props.put(null, null);
  props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
  props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "gatewaycallbacktopngroup");
  props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, true);
  props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "100");
  props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "15000");
  return props;
 }

 @Bean
 public Deserializer < String > stringKeyDeserializer() {
  return new StringDeserializer();
 }

 @Bean
 public Deserializer < GatewayCallBackMessage > gatewayCallBackMessageJsonValueDeserializer() {
  return new JsonDeserializer < GatewayCallBackMessage > (GatewayCallBackMessage.class);
 }

 @Bean
 public ConsumerFactory < String, GatewayCallBackMessage > consumerFactory() {
  return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory < > (consumerProps(),
   stringKeyDeserializer(), gatewayCallBackMessageJsonValueDeserializer());
 }


 @Bean
 public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory < String, GatewayCallBackMessage > kafkaListenerContainerFactory1() {
  ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory < String, GatewayCallBackMessage > factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory < > ();


  factory.setConcurrency(1);
  factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
  return factory;
 }


}
```

Here is the exception trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory<java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1486) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at com.ns.services.pn.main.PushNotificationServiceLauncher.main(PushNotificationServiceLauncher.java:28) [bin/:na]

2017-03-24 00:27:04.621 ERROR 51773 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 1 of method kafkaListenerContainerFactory in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory' that could not be found.
    - Bean method 'kafkaConsumerFactory' in 'KafkaAutoConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'consumerFactory'


Action:

Consider revisiting the conditions above or defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory' in your configuration.
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change your `kafkaListenerContainerFactory1` bean name to `kafkaListenerContainerFactory`.

The auto config factory is looking for a `ConsumerFactory<Object, Object>` which doesn't match yours and it is

```
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
```

Whereas the consumer factory is...

```
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(ConsumerFactory.class)
public ConsumerFactory<?, ?> kafkaConsumerFactory() {
```

Or, disable Kafka auto configuration.

Comment: I have the same pb and I want to disable the autoconfiguration but still use @EnableConfigurationProperties(KafkaProperties.class). I'm using Kafka Spring in a jar that'll be used by other Spring Boot apps. So how can I disable the auto configuration in my jar and also on any Spring Boot app that depends on it ?

Comment: You should ask a new question rather than commenting on this one - it's a different question. You can exclude specific auto configuration classes in the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have posted a new question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43633263/spring-boot-excluding-some-autoconfigured-beans

Comment: FWIIW, this shouldn't be required anymore since `v2.3.0.RELEASE`. Fixed by https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/19221

Answer (score 4):

1、KafkaListener Configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaListenerConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setBatchListener(true);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, environment.getProperty("spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers"));
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "1111");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        return props;
    }
}
```

2、KafkaListener Setting

```
@KafkaListener(topics = {KafkaTopicChannel.INPUT_CHANNEL}, containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
public void listen(List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> list) {
    logger.debug(String.valueOf(list.size()));
}
```